# Event of jsp page Handel in servlet

Tags: jsp, events, servlets

i want to create jsp page
that jsp page contain many of the checkbox
and at the time checked of checkbox

display data from the database in same jsp page.

so how can i get that checkbox in my servlet so that i can use Event class for doing...

Comment: i have 1 jsp page 
which contain many checkbox
if any check box checked then in div tag display related data from the server
so how can i use Event in servlets

Comment: you need javascript/jquery to achieve that, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax) to get some idea, and post the jsp page and servlet to your question if you got any problem.